# i try to run my code but gives an error whats the underlying problem

Tags: python

pretty much the same as my code book whats wrong whats wrong with my f string in here
the code :

```
letter1 = 'we are trying hard'
letter2 = 'and hopefully things will go well'
whole_letter = f"i want to say that {letter1.upper()} 
and by considering all the things {letter2.upper()}"
print(whole_letter)
```

and the error is this winch i dont get whats is underlying problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqjMu.png)
why the heck i get dislikes give likes people if you think its unfair iam just learning

Comment: If you want the string to span multiple lines including the newline you need to use triple quotes (`"""`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a simple string on 2 lines. You can fix it like this.

```
letter1 = 'we are trying hard'
letter2 = 'and hopefully things will go well'
whole_letter = f"""i want to say that {letter1.upper()} 
and by considering all the things {letter2.upper()}"""
print(whole_letter)
```